# Retrieve jquery-ui dialog's div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

When we apply `$().dialog()` in an object, jquery-ui puts it inside a `<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget">`, with a `<div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header">` before it.

After the creation of this dialog around the main object, how can we get that ui-dialog object so that we can execute other JavaScript commands in it?

The best I could do was use `.parent(".ui-dialog")` in the main object, is there a better way to do it?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the object? Do you want to delegate an event to it? or are you trying to change the CSS? Please clarify.

Comment: I wanna add an id attribute to it and apply CSS to it, and also retrieve its position when it is moved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be looking for this:

```
var widget = $( "#yourdialogsource" ).dialog( "widget" );
```

This will get you the jQuery object of the wrapper for your dialog.